# Why was screenPlay only able to air 1 hour of the Overwatch World Cup?

Tags: distribution

On 23/07/2017, screenPlay aired the live broadcast Australia VS Sweden Group Match of the Overwatch World Cup from Sydney. However after an hour they had to stop,  directing everyone to the website to continue watching.

The AFL, Cricket and Tennis air for much longer, particularly the Tennis went over what time it was scheduled because a match kept going and none of those were on the TV Channel screenPlay was on (it was Seven Mate (63)).

So why was screenPlay only able to air an hour of it?

Comment: Maybe they were able to but there weren't enough viewers ? I don't think that many OW players will bother watching on TV. We're all on our PCs watching the stream.

Comment: How do you know they "had" to stop? As Liquid said, thy may have just decided to only show an hour

Comment: @StevenVascellaro because the TV Guide (which has been set for a couple of days) has it scheduled only for an hour and as i said there was a Tennis Match that went over it's scheduled time and that continued to go (can't remember who the match was but it was talk about in the news for it going so long) so it's not like that with live events they have to. Viewer count would be irrelevant since i can't think how they would get that for something before it aired

Comment: @Memor-X If it was planned to be an hour in advance, then that doesn't mean they were *forced* to stop. That may have been the plan all along to make room for other events